# IoC Unity - Dependency on middle tier

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm kind of a newbie to Unity, but I wonder if the following scenario is feasible:

I have an MVC app that uses Unity for IoC.  One of it's references is "Service1".  Service1, in turn uses Service2.  I would like to implement IoC also for Service1 -> Service2, but the latter is not visible to the MVC app (and I would like to keep it like that).

From what I gather, in order to implement DI, I have to make Service2 visible to the MVC app.  Is there an alternative implementation to this?

Is it possible to have Unity referenced in Service1, so that will take care of it's dependencies there?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ioc/DI - Why do I have to reference all layers/assemblies in entry application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/300376/does-having-di-happen-in-the-composition-root-go-against-the-whole-point-of-depe

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UnityContainer in Service 1 to resolve the IService2 but you need to have registered to the ioc that IService2 is resolved with type Service2.

Otherwise you can just make an instance of Service2 in Service1 yourself (but you might not want that).